# Is it possible to go to another page, wait until the user returns to the original page, then continue the function?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, xamarin.forms, edit

I'm giving the user a page to edit a listview items' contents.

```
public async void OnEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender);

    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        var selectedZone = (ViewModels.ZoneViewModel)menuItem.CommandParameter;

        // Send to edit page with selectedzones' contents.
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ZonePage(selectedZone.Name, selectedZone.Address, selectedZone.IdentitySource, selectedZone.Username, selectedZone.Password));

        //Wait until user returns from page

        //Edit logic here
    }    
}
```

This is the contextaction that takes the user there. So after sending the user to another page I want to wait until he's done editing on the edit page, then return to finish the function.

I was planning to do this a different way but it didn't turn out the way I wanted. I need `var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender);` to get the selected item from the list and don't know another way to make this work in my situation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **MessagingCenter** to communicate between two pages. Xamarin.Forms **MessagingCenter** enables view models and other components to communicate with without having to know anything about each other besides a simple Message contract.

To pass an argument with the message, specify the argument Type in the Subscribe generic arguments and in the Action signature.

```
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string> (this, "Hi", (sender, arg) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
    // using the 'arg' parameter which is a string
});
```

To send the message with argument, include the Type generic parameter and the value of the argument in the Send method call.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string> (this, "Hi", "John");
```

[Here is the more detailed official documentation with examples.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I got this working but now I have a problem, I think. I need to send 4 strings and 1 int instead of only one string. Can I do this with one message instead of 5? Or is this not possible?

Comment: According to docs any C# object can be passed. So I assume that you can pass a list of objects also. Look at the document for more information.